# Startswith function for searching an array

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is giving me some trouble.  The code below returns the error message "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".  The function should just search through the values in the accountlist and return the one that starts with the submitted string.  In the example, submitting "000555" should return 0.

```js
var accountlist = [{
    "value": "000555 - TEST ACCOUNT NAME1",
    "data": "184"
}, {
    "value": "006666 - TEST ACCOUNT NAME2",
    "data": "450"
}, {
    "value": "007777 - TEST ACCOUNT NAME2",
    "data": "451"
}];

function startswith(inputlist, searchkey, inputstring) {
    var searchlength = inputstring.length;
    console.log("starting search");

    for (var il = 0; il < inputlist.length; il++) {
        if (inputlist[il].window[searchkey].substring(0, (searchlength - 1)) == inputstring) {
            console.log("FOUND IT " + il + "      " + inputstring);
            return il
        }
    }
}

startswith(accountlist, "value","000555");
```

Comment: Why `.window`? Seems like you just want `inputlist[il][searchkey]...`

Comment: Also, `(searchlength - 1)` will guarantee you'll never get a match. The ending index is non-inclusive. Simpler would be `if (inputlist[il][searchkey].startsWith(inputstring)) {...`

Comment: ...lastly,  the whole thing could be reduced down quite a bit by using `.findIndex()`... `inputlist.findIndex(obj => obj[searchkey].startsWith(inputstring))`

Comment: where did you copy this code from?

Comment: @squint you're right, i just removed ".window" and "-1" and it works perfectly.  I also was able to simplify it by using startWith instead of a substring.

Comment: @Josan i would like to blame my failed function on somebody else but I keyed every character.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the find function:

```js
var accountlist = [{
    "value": "000555 - TEST ACCOUNT NAME1",
    "data": "184"
}, {
    "value": "006666 - TEST ACCOUNT NAME2",
    "data": "450"
}, {
    "value": "007777 - TEST ACCOUNT NAME2",
    "data": "451"
}];
var searchString = '000555';
var result = accountlist.findIndex((account) => { return account.value.startsWith(searchString);}, searchString)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Or `findIndex` rather, since he expects `0` as a return value

Answer (score 8):

You should use **filter** & **startsWith** method.

---

The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

---

The startsWith() method determines whether a string begins with the characters of a specified string, returning true or false as appropriate.

```js
const stateList = [
        { name: 'Alabama', shortName: 'AL' },
        { name: 'Alaska', shortName: 'AK' },
        { name: 'Arizona', shortName: 'AZ' },
        { name: 'Arkansas', shortName: 'AR' },
        { name: 'California', shortName: 'CA' },
        { name: 'Colorado', shortName: 'CO' },
        { name: 'Connecticut', shortName: 'CT' },
        { name: 'Delaware', shortName: 'DE' },
        { name: 'District of Columbia', shortName: 'DC' },
        { name: 'Florida', shortName: 'FL' },
        { name: 'Georgia', shortName: 'GA' },
  ];
var filterValue = 'Ala';
var result = stateList.filter(option => option.name.startsWith(filterValue));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With squints suggestions ended up with this function which works as expected.

```js
var accountlist = [{
    "value": "000555 - TEST ACCOUNT NAME1",
    "data": "184"
}, {
    "value": "006666 - TEST ACCOUNT NAME2",
    "data": "450"
}, {
    "value": "007777 - TEST ACCOUNT NAME2",
    "data": "451"
}];

function findstartswith(inputlist, searchkey, inputstring) {
    for (var il = 0; il < inputlist.length; il++) {
        if (inputlist[il][searchkey].startsWith(inputstring)) {
            alert("FOUND IT " + il + "      " + inputstring);
           return il;
        }
    }
}

findstartswith(accountlist, "value","006666");
```